# adding @Transient over MappedSuperClass attributes

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently I have a MappedSuperClass called BaseEntity, which I am extending over all my entity classes

```
 @MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PersistentObject extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1701208353317749260L;

    protected Tenant tenant;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TENANT_ID")
    public Tenant getTenant() {
        return this.tenant;
    }

    public void setTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }
@Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    public int getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
```

In my entities which contains static data, I dont need tenant_id to be added where as i need all the other atrributes in BaseEntity.

Currently I can only change my column name and so on using AttributeOverrides and AssosciationOverrides, so how can i add @Transient over unneeded fields in MappedSuperClass?

Comment: Did you try adding @Transient over tenant field? If you use field access ofcourse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :). ya tried it too but still I am getting the column in my subclass

Comment: Could you post your code with @Id field?

Comment: added the needed code, there is no @Id field as it is a mappedsuperclass

Comment: You are physically mapping Tenant to tenant_id column in database.. How do you imagine it not being persistent? Maybe you need to look to inverse mapping?

Comment: I need tenant_id to be persistent in some entities whereas in other entities which are having static data, I need the tenant_id to be non persistent even after extending the MappedSuperClass either by adding @Transient over the field